# Webapp shows 404 page after project renaming

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven-3, m2eclipse

I have been working on this web application using Eclipse and m2e (maven plugin for Eclipse).

After a while I decide to change the project name in eclipse doing: Right click on project >> refactor >> rename

Following this I see a few errors coming up, mostly to do with classpath configuration & java versions mismatch. I fix them, adding the maven dependencies to the build path, and updating the java versions to be used during compilation & run time.

I rebuild my web app & restart my server (Tomcat in this case). Open my browser to go to my app's root url. And I get a 404 page (everything looks fine in the console btw).

I've been going through my buildpath and classpath config to double check if anything was coming from there but everything seems fine. I'm confused and unsure where to look at.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the path with the new name? or still using the old name? the path should look like http://myserver/newappname/

Comment: Have the tried to clean-up your server instance in Eclipse and then running the new web project on Fresh Server? Also don't forgot to update the new web application name in the URL with the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your Setup. If you are using the default path, it is (as Kal said) myserver/newappname.

If you are using a url that you have configured in webserver for easier readability like (myapp.myserver.com) you would have to change the redirection in your server from your old appname to the new one.

Comment: Karl was correct, this was simply a url change... sometimes url suggestions in browsers do NOT help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually,
 `404 HTTP` `standard response code` indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.

```
 1. Check your path with newapplication name.
 2. See inside your server, Is there a resource with (newNameApp.war)?
 3. As you are using maven, try to build the project and see the log, by which name war is generated, and where the war got placed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation and simply restarted Eclipse and no more 404 afterward